# R Markdown ioslides bibliography continue on next slide

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, bibtex, ioslides

In an ioslides presentation, is there a way to break the slide with BibTex bibliography into multiples slides? I have a large BibTex bibliography and many citations, and the references overflow the `## References` slide.

Comment: @scoa That duplicate has no answers and is therefore not a proper duplicate imo.

Comment: @Jaap but it's the same poster asking the same question. Wouldn't a bounty be a more proper way to attract attention on an old question?

Comment: @scoa Adding a bounty is indeed the best solution. Closed now.

Comment: I can't believe this still hasn't been answered